# How to convert a directory to a ZIP?

Tags: python-3.7, zip

I wanted to know how to convert a `file (x)` directly to a `ZIP (x.zip)`, and convert it back into a normal file, using `python (3.7)`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive)

```
import shutil
#creating archive
shutil.make_archive(output_filename, 'zip', dir_name)
#unpacking archive
shutil.unpack_archive(input_filename, extract_dir, 'zip')
```

you can also do with [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

```
import os
import zipfile
#creating zip file
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("mydirectory"):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
#extracting zip file
with zipfile.ZipFile("myzipfile.zip", 'r') as zip: 
    zip.extractall()
```

Answer (score 1):

**For zipping and Unzipping without password protected:**

For zipping the File, You can use `pyminizip` module

```
import pyminizip
compression_level = 5 # 1-9
pyminizip.compress("/home/paulsteven/src.txt",'src', "dst.zip", None, compression_level)
```

For Unzipping the File, Use `Zipfile` module

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
with ZipFile('/home/paulsteven/dst.zip') as zf:
    zf.extractall()
```

**For zipping and Unzipping with password protected:**

For ZIP:

```
import pyminizip
compression_level = 5 # 1-9
pyminizip.compress("/home/paulsteven/src.txt",'src', "dst.zip", "password", compression_level)
```

For UNZIP:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('/home/paulsteven/dst.zip') as zf:
    zf.extractall(pwd=b'password')
```

Answer (score 0):

To crack a ZIP file has been protected:

```
import threading
from zipfile import ZipFile

def ext(f, pw):
    try:
        f.extractall(pwd=pw)
        print('Cracked the .zip file')
        print(':::::  %s' % pw)
    except:
        pass

f = 'file.zip'

pw = open('password.txt', 'r').readline()
for p in pw:
    crack=threading.Thread(target=ext, args=[f, p])
    crack.start()
```